# Доступ по домену к виртуальной машине

Tags: openvz, виртуальная-машина, bind9

Имеется несколько виртуальных машин на одном сервере с OpenVZ. Расскажите, как правильно организовать доступ к каждой из машин по доменному имени?

Хочу получить что-то вроде этого:

1. host: s1.example.com
2. ve1: ve1.s1.example.com
3. ve2: ve2.s1.example.com

Предполагаю, что для этого необходимо использовать DNS сервер на хосте, но даже не представляю, с чего начать.

Answer (score 1):

ip один? dns тут ни при чем особо... nginx на хосте или на третьей машине ставьте, он будет обратным прокси для других виртуальных машин.

Comment: А если мне нужно что-то, кроме web-сервера? С одним ip никак не получится?